# Official docs of design components tags for vuejs is needed please

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

As I am new to vuejs, I would like to know which website contains a composite of all the design component tags?

In other words, in angular when I want to add a checkbox for example I go to this website:
https://clarity.design/documentation/checkboxes

What is equivalent to that website for vuejs, please

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which component framework you use, personally I use Vuetify : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

You are free to do your own research for Vue component frameworks.
You can take a look at Quasar:

https://quasar.dev/

Recommending libraries is however beyond the scope of StackOverflow in general.